# Minimum, Average and Maximum in columns

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

I have the next question, I'll like to have TWO minimun values, a maximun value and the average for this input:

```
 Call 1 1.160 ms
 Call 2 0.163 ms
 Call 3 1.154 ms
 Call 4 1.029 ms
 Call 5 0.291 ms
 Call 6 1.186 ms
 Call 7 1.089 ms
 Call 8 1.122 ms
 Call 9 0.975 ms
 Call 10 1.224 ms
 Call 11 0.965 ms
 Call 12 1.047 ms
 Call 13 1.138 ms
 Call 14 1.217 ms
 Call 15 1.189 ms
 Call 16 1.115 ms
 Call 17 0.950 ms
 Call 18 1.112 ms
 Call 19 1.227 ms
 Call 20 1.071 ms
 Call 21 1.108 ms
 Call 22 1.191 ms
 Call 23 1.139 ms
 Call 24 1.032 ms
 Call 25 1.305 ms
 Call 26 1.085 ms
 Call 27 1.404 ms
 Call 28 1.282 ms
 Call 29 1.031 ms
 Call 30 1.018 ms
 Call 31 1.308 ms
 Call 32 1.299 ms
 Call 33 1.096 ms
 Call 34 1.129 ms
 Call 35 1.271 ms
 Call 36 1.035 ms
 Call 37 1.238 ms
 Call 38 1.150 ms
 Call 39 1.042 ms
 Call 40 0.948 ms
```

I've been using those commands:

```
 awk 'min=="" || $3 < min {min=$3; minline=$0}; END{ print minline}'

 awk '{ if ($3>max) {max=$3; line=$0} } END {print line }'

 awk '{s+=$3} END{print "Number of Calls: "NR, "\nAverage: "s/(NR)}'
```

The output is this:

```
 Minimun: Call 18 0.212 ms
 Maximun: Call 27 1.404 ms
 Number of Calls: 40
 Average: 1.1071
```

But I need to have 2 minimun values, one of them is showed above but the other one should be any number greather than 0.800. I've trying this:

```
 awk 'min=="0.800" || $3 < min {min=$3; minline=$0}; END{ print minline}'
```

But it shows me nothing. Please, I need your help to place this in a script.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: "the other one should be any number greather than 0.800. " pls explain this. why it would be a min?

Comment: It is hard to explain, is a requeriment for me too..

Comment: if it is "any number", the max number is also one number >0.800, you can just take that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{min=999}
{a[NR]=$0;if($3<min){min=$3;m[1]=NR;}if($3>max){max=$3;m[2]=NR;}m[3]+=$3;}
END{print "Min:"a[m[1]];
        print "Max:"a[m[2]];
        print "Number Of Calls:" NR;
        print "Avg:"m[3]/NR;
        t=max>0.800?a[m[2]]:"None";
        print "Any greater than 0.800:"t}' yourFile
```

output:

```
Min:Call 2 0.163 ms
Max:Call 27 1.404 ms
Number Of Calls:40
Avg:1.08837
Any greater than 0.800:Call 27 1.404 ms
```

Note:  for the "any number greater than 0.800", i just checked the Max, if it >0.800,print it as the magic number. if not, print None.

**EDIT**

changes for OP's comment:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{min=mag=999}
{a[NR]=$0;if($3<min){min=$3;m[1]=NR;}if($3>max){max=$3;m[2]=NR;}if($3>0.800&&$3<mag){mag=$3;m[4]=NR} m[3]+=$3;}
END{print "Min:"a[m[1]];
        print "Max:"a[m[2]];
        print "Number Of Calls:" NR;
        print "Avg:"m[3]/NR;
        print "Any greater than 0.800:"a[m[4]]}' yourFile
```

output:

```
Min:Call 2 0.163 ms
Max:Call 27 1.404 ms
Number Of Calls:40
Avg:1.08837
Any greater than 0.800:Call 40 0.948 ms
```

Comment: It's really great, sry for not be specific but could you fix your script to obtain the minimum value greather than 0.800 please?

Comment: @Martin_911 see Edit in answer

Answer (score 1):

You want the two minimal values:

```
awk '{ if (min1==""||$3<=min1) { min2=min1; line2=line1; min1=$3; line1=$0; }
       else if (min2=="" || $3 <= min2)                { min2=$3; line2=$0; } }
       END{ print line1; print line2}'
```

output:

```
Call 2 0.163 ms
Call 5 0.291 ms
```

You want the minimal value and the second minimal value grater than 0.8 ms:

```
awk '{ if (min1==""||$3<=min1) { if(min1>0.8) {min2=min1; line2=line1;} min1=$3; line1=$0; }
       else if ($3>0.8 && (min2=="" || $3 <= min2))                   { min2=$3; line2=$0; } }
       END{ print line1; print line2}'
```

output:

```
 Call 2 0.163 ms
 Call 40 0.948 ms
```

Comment: I'm sry for my ignorance but where did you declare the first time should be the minimun and the other one should be greather than 0.800?

Comment: Actually the output should be like this:

      Minimum: Call 18 0.212 ms
      Minimum Call greather than 0.800: Call 17 0.950 ms
      Maximum: Call 27 1.404 ms
      Number of Calls: 40
      Average: 1.1071

Comment: thank you so much. Could you please let me edit the input and try again please with your script please?

Comment: I already did it, u'll be able to see that the Call 2 is 0.163 and Call 5 is 0.291 ms. When I run ur script (with the new input) it shows me Call 2 0.163 and Call 5 0.291

Comment: OK, I see the issue. How come I did not see that. I tested the case... Ok I am fixing it ;-)

Comment: Yes, it is correct ;-)   I thought `Call 2` was greater than `Call 1`

Comment: OK, I understand: You want the minimal value and the second minimal value grater than 0.8 ms. isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Here is my solution in Perl, in which I am a newbie, but would like to learn:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n

BEGIN { $min1 = 9999; $min2 = 9999; $max = -1; }

($label, $callNumber, $callTime, $ms) = split;

$sum += $callTime;
if ($max < $callTime) {
    $max = $callTime;
    $maxLine = $_; 
}   

if ($min1 > $callTime) {
    $min1 = $callTime;
    $min1Line = $_; 
}   

if ($min2 > $callTime && $min1 != $callTime) {
    $min2 = $callTime;
    $min2Line = $_; 
}   

END {
    $average = $sum / $.; 
    print "Minimum1:        $min1Line";
    print "Minimum2:        $min2Line";
    print "Maximum:         $maxLine";
    print "Number of Calls: $.\n";
    print "Average:         $average\n";
}
```

The only tricky part is to calculate $min2, which is the next-to-smallest value. My script seems long, but I believe it is easier to understand and maintain than some other solutions.

### Solution 2

This solution only calculates the two min, one max, but it is relatively short:

```
sort -k 3,3 -n data.txt | sed -n '1,2s/^/Min: /p;$s/^/Max: /p'
```